# url is getting displayed even in standalone mode in progressive web app

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I trying to create a web app with "add to home screen function" , when the user has added the web app to his home screen then ,i'm using window.location.href in my HTML ,to call a new page , Everthing is working as expected but the url is getting displayed even in standalone mode. here is the screenshot of the url being displayed even in standalone mode.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTXH7.jpg

Comment: I think you need to test this on your own website and not of others. What does your website in standalone mode look like?

Comment: The IP of the server is just getting displayed, for ex if my web app is running 10.1.1.52 , then i could see the server IP at the top as same as it is shown in the image.

Comment: Based on the image, it looks like a non-PWA that's been added to home screen. To see whether your app is recognized as a PWA, hold the app icon. If a menu pops up with options such as App Info, then it is a PWA. Otherwise you have other issues that's preventing your app from acting like a PWA, such as invalid SSL certificate, or start_url does not load, etc.

Answer (score 1):

URL in standalone mode is a security measure taken by Google chrome while redirecting to other servers(Websites) and to avoid users from visiting malicious site. Any hacker can easily mimic a payment gateway and redirect user in his web app using full screen standalone mode.user will never be able to make out that he'll be visiting a fake site.
Please check the below link, I've already answered this question in detail.

[url showing in address bar in progressive web apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352302/url-showing-in-address-bar-in-progressive-web-apps/46664066#46664066)