# url showing in address bar in progressive web apps

Tags: progressive-web-apps, progressive

We are developing progressive web app, in android phone, we are seeing url in address s shown in below, 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jKQ3.png)

Steps we have taken care in Manifest.json,

```
"display": "standalone",
"orientation": "portrait",
"Scope": "/",
"start_url": "/Home/Test",
```

Starting page always which is `http://localhost:52432/Home/test`, displaying perfectly in stand alone, but when we click other tabs then it started displaying url in the address bar with lock symbol.

Can any body help me on this, appreciate all your efforts.

Thanks,
Karthik Nerella

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to such case yet?

Answer (score 1):

URL in PWA is a security measure taken by google chrome to avoid the users navigating to a malicious site without proper notice. Say a hacker creates a fake payment gateway and redirects you there in standalone mode. How would you know whether it is legit or not? You say that "http://localhost:52432/Home/test" won't show the URL, might be because it's your start_url in manifest.json. Try moving all the pages to Home. For Example, if you have "localhost:52432/Profile/page", move it to "localhost:52432/Home/page". This might help you.